# How get data templates for unit tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, mocking, tdd

I need to write a unit test for this method:

```
public void MethodToTest(Data data)
{
     // ... some actions with data   
}
```

Data class:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    // ... hundred other properties
}
```

In my test I need some template object of `Data` type to manipulate it.
But this class has too many complex properties to write this "template" manually.
In real program `Data` objects are retrieved from DB. While debugging I can serialize some of them into XML or JSON. But then I need somehow deserialize it for test. Is believe there are a common patterns and tools to solve such issues. So what is a proper way to do it?

Comment: Have you seen something like AutoFixture before? It helps to auto generate classes and populate them with data. https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `MethodToTest` only uses a few parts of the `Data` class, you can define an interface that segregates those properties:

```
public interface PersonalData {
  string Name {get; set; }
  int Age {get; set; }
  string Surname {get; set; }
}

public void MethodToTest (PersonalData data) { ... }
```

and have `Data` implement this interface

```
public class Data: PersonalData { ... }
```

Then you can use a test class that implements `PersonalData` for your test (or you might use a mocking framework to generate an implementation of `PersonalData`).